# adding external python tool to PYTHONPATH after conda initialization - not working

Tags: python, module, initialization, conda

as the title says, I am attempting to import a python module but it does not seem to be working in the conda environment.

My conda environment is initialized at login (via `/opt/conda/bin/conda init bash` run). I have prepended to PYTHONPATH the path to the external python library, opened the conda iterations of python (/opt/conda/bin/ipython and /opt/conda/bin/python3) and the module is not found (ModuleNotFoundError). When I run the system level python (/bin/python3) the module imports without issue.

How can I get the python module in the PYTHONPATH to be accessible in the conda iteration of python? I am trying to set this up so that it is independent of the user's preference of conda python or the system level version of python.

Comment: What is the path to the module and what have you added to `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: It is a .so file in a lib directory where the software was installed. I have added the directory with the file (/path/to/lib) in it to the PYTHONPATH and it works with /bin/python3 but not /opt/conda/bin/python3.

Comment: You cannot import a `.so` file directly... Run `/bin/python3`. In the interactive `python` session that will start, do `import <module name>` and `print <module name>`which should print the path of the actual `.py` file that is being imported. I am assuming that the software that you installed also put some py files in the site-packages of `/bin/python3`

Comment: The system level python seems to be reading in the .so file directly:


`>>> import aoflagger`


`>>> aoflagger.__file__
'/path/to/aoflagger/aoflagger-v3.3.0/lib/aoflagger.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'`


`>>> print(aoflagger)
<module 'aoflagger' from '/path/to/aoflagger/aoflagger-v3.3.0/lib/aoflagger.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>`

Comment: I found that I can use `importlib.util` to import a .so file:

`import importlib.util`
`spec=importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('aoflagger','/path/to/aoflagger/aoflagger-v3.3.0/lib/libaoflagger.so')`
`aoflagger = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)`